# Deserialize Sendbird message CreatedAt data

Tags: ios, swift, deserialization, sendbird

I am trying to get the dates of the message send date in String format from sendbird messages, but don't know how to deserialize the messages.

currently I am just getting a mess of numbers like follows:

```
1506267806611
```

I currently store the serialized date in the variable below, but can't figure out what's needed to deserialize in swift 3

```
var msgDate = userMessage.createdAt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a timestamp. You can convert it to a date using

```
Date(timeIntervalSince1970: msgDate)
```

Comment: What is the first section of the date returned? `49701-09-23 04:03:31 +0000`

Comment: At first glance it appeared to be a Timestamp, so in this case I think it would be better to look into Sendbird's documentation to see what format the dates are in.

Comment: for this case the answer sufficed, as I am parsing the string and dropping the year anyway.  As long as I got the month, day and time I am all set.  I was just curious

Answer (score 0):

You should divide it by 1000 to change it to seconds not milliseconds, so it will be like:

```
let msgDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(userMessage.createdAt) / 1000 )
```